# replace string in comma delimiter file using nawk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, nawk

I need to implement the if condition in the below nawk command to process input file if the third column has more that three digit.Pls help with the command what i am doing wrong as it is not working.

inputfile.txt

```
123 | abc | 321456 | tre 

213 | fbc | 342    | poi
```

outputfile.txt

```
123 | abc | 321### | tre 

213 | fbc | 342    | poi
```

---

```
cat inputfile.txt | nawk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; OFS="|"} {if($3 > 3) $3=substr($3, 1, 3)"###" print}'
```

Comment: you  may just need a `;` between the "###" string and the cmd `print`. Good luck.

Comment: I don't see any commas...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk 'length($3) > 3 { $3=substr($3, 1, 3)"###" } 1 ' FS=\| OFS=\| test1.txt
```

Comment: Since the whitespace will be part of the field, you'll have to do more work

Answer (score 0):

This works with gawk:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=' | ' '
    $3 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{4,}/ {$3 = substr($3,1,3) "###"} 
    1
' inputfile.txt
```

It won't preserve the whitespace so you might want to pipe through `column -t`